# Modifying type hierarchies at runtime

Tags: c#, multiple-inheritance

I've been having trouble even defining what I am looking for.

I am writing an app to determine winners in a tournament. I would like my base class to be able to change it's inheritance based on how many people are playing, given that multiple inheritance is not an option, and probably wouldn't be a very good one the more i think on it.

I see something along the lines of

```
class Base
{
   //Constructor receiving the quantity of players
   public Base (int quantityOfPlayers)
   {
      //Changes Base inheritance dynamically based on QuantityOfPlayers
      switch (quantityOfPlayers)
      {
         case 4: (Base : FourPlayers);
         case 5: (Base : FivePlayers);
      }
   }
}
```

But of course i can't seem to find a means (if there is one) of dynamically changing the inheritance like that. Otherwise I'm stuck using more complicated means though each of the getter and setter functions are going to be essentially the same.

---

Very good solutions. let me add that I'm using a GUI not the console.

I have to think on this, the factory class is good, but it has convinced me I'm over thinking my approach.

Comment: Changing inheritance based on number of players playing doesn't sound like a good `Software Design`. Maybe if you elaborate why you need to change the inheritance bases on the number of players we could suggest a different optimal way of solving this problem.

Comment: @OrelEraki normally would agree but for a game see how this would be very useful for something like menu navigation

Comment: @Franky_D my answer specifics look convoluted because I am providing an entire example in one area, basically you would have your base functionality, defined contracts in interface, and in the base classes if you wanted to override a specific element of a contract you use `IContractName.MethodName` syntax

Answer (score 2):

There is a software design pattern called [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) for this kind of situation.

Define an interface for the game strategy

```
public interface IGameStrategy
{
    // Things that depend on the number of players, go here...
}
```

The right strategy gets injected into the game through [constructor injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Constructor_injection)

```
public class Game
{
    private IGameStrategy _strategy;

    // Constructor injection
    public Game(IGameStrategy strategy)
    {
        _strategy = strategy;
    }

    // Things common to all types of games go here...
}
```

Define a [factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) method like this:

```
private IGameStrategy CreateGameStrategy(int numberOfPlayers)
    switch (numberOfPlayers)
    {
        case 4:
            return FourPlayersStrategy();
        case 5:
            return FivePlayersStrategy();
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid number of players");
    }
}
```

Then create a game like this:

```
var game = new Game(CreateGameStrategy(numberOfPlayers));
```

Of course the strategy classes implement the interface. They can do so directly or they can inherit a common abstract base class implementing the interface.

The game logic is split into things common to all types of games implemented in  the `Game` class and things specific to the number of players implemented in the strategy classes.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a factory class that generates the proper class based on the number of players:

```
public class PlayerQtyFactory
{
    //You can add any other args you might need as well
    public BaseClass CreatePlayerQty(int numPlayers)
    {

      switch (numPlayers)
      {
          Case 2:
            return new TwoPlayers();

          Case 3:
            return new ThreePlayers();

      {
    }
}
```

Without knowing more about what you are trying to do, it is hard to say if this is the best approach, but it is certainly **A** aproach.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular situation I would use a factoryesque (or just plan factory) solution

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Tester
{
    //declare common functionality
        public interface ISharedFunctionality 
        {
            //put all shared functionality here
            void SomeMethod();
            void SomeOtherMethod();

            void DifferentMethod();
            string Name {get;set;}
        }

        public interface ISinglePlayerFunctionality : ISharedFunctionality
        {
            //put single player functionality here
            void SomeOtherMethod();
            void SomeMethod();
        }

        public interface IMultiplePlayerFunctionality : ISharedFunctionality
        {
            //put multiplayer functionality here
            void DifferentMethod();
            void SomeMethod();
        }

        public class ImplementationBase : ISharedFunctionality
        {
            //shared implementation here
            public void SomeMethod()
            {
                //do stuff
                Console.WriteLine("In Base");
            }
            public void SomeOtherMethod()
            {
                //one you don't want to inherit in multiplayer
                Console.WriteLine("In Base");
            }
            public void DifferentMethod() 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("In Base");
            }


            public string Name
            {
                get;
                set;
            }


        }

        public class MultiPlayerImplementation : ImplementationBase, IMultiplePlayerFunctionality
        {
            //multiplay impl
            // you inherit some method but don't want to inherit 
            //SomeOtherMethod when cast to ISharedFunctionality
            void ISharedFunctionality.SomeMethod()
            {
                //when cast to ISharedFunctionality this method will execute not inherited
                Console.WriteLine("In MutilPlayImplementation");
            } 
        }

        public class SinglePlayerImplementation : ImplementationBase , ISinglePlayerFunctionality
        {
            //singleplay impl

            void ISharedFunctionality.SomeOtherMethod()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("In SinglePlayerImplementation" );
            }


        }

        public class Factory 
        {
            //logic to decide impl here
            public ISharedFunctionality Create(int numberOfPlayer)
            {
                if (numberOfPlayer == 1)
                {
                    return new SinglePlayerImplementation();
                }
                else if(numberOfPlayer > 1)
                {
                    return new MultiPlayerImplementation();
                }

                return null;
            }
        }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var factory = new Factory();
            var results = new[]{factory.Create(1) , factory.Create(2) };

            int j=0;
            foreach (var i in results) 
            {
                ///for single player will be base
                ///multiplaryer will be mutliplayer
                i.SomeMethod();
                //for single player will be single player
                // for multiplayer will be base
                i.SomeOtherMethod();
                i.DifferentMethod();
                i.Name = "Item-Number-" + j;
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The benefit to this is two fold, you now no longer have ambiguity in terms of what method is being called, and you have a unified place to construct future implementations based off of similair contracts (i.e. three player behavior, different menu behavior, and it might be even less code if you want the exact same methods to just behave differently